# Database for corporate website

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a corporate website which has these areas:

- Home page
- About us
- Services
- News
- Contact

I'm in doubt how can I optimize the database to store the data for some of these pages. For the `News` and `Services` there is no secret. But I'm in doubt with the `About us` and `Contact` pages, for example. They are very similar, but have some different informations. This can scale to other pages if needed, this is why I'm trying to optimize, because I may have a page `Work with us` etc..

- `About us`: Has just a text box and an image header.
- `Contact`: Has a text box, image header but also a map.
- `Work with us`: Has a text box and an image header.

I was thinking of using a table like this:

```
ID | page | id_gallery | text | map
```

But as the website grows, I would need to manually add more fields. I could also create a single table for each page, but it will always have only one row, I don't think it's the best way to go.

Is there a better approach to this scenario?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel; use WordPress like everybody else.

Comment: @mustaccio What if I can't or don't want to?

Comment: Then you can at least look at the WordPress data model for guidance. Why do you think you even need a database for a static web site with 5 pages? Unless, of course, this contrived example comes from some sort of a homework, which you then should have stated.